# Arcpy doesn't recognize spatialite tables after editing with QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, spatialite

I'm working on a project that would like to use spatialite as a go-between for field edits using QGIS/IntramapsRoam and then loading the data to a file geodatabase.

The workflow is as follows
Spatialite (created in ArcGIS using 'SPATIALITE' geometry) -> QGIS -> ArcGIS 10.2

I'm running in to a compatibility issue with arcpy and spatialite that renders my workflow impossible and am wondering if this has been encountered before and if there are any known solutions/workarounds.

```
#Create the database
sqllite_database = r'.\test.sqlite'
arcpy.gp.CreateSQLiteDatabase(sqlite_database, “SPATIALITE”)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r'.\test.sqlite',
                                    'points', "POINT")
arcpy.AddField_management(r'.test.sqlite\main.points',
                          "num_field", "TEXT")
```

After creating the database, I can access it with arcpy.

[image]

I then add a point in QGIS and save edits.

[image]

I can no longer access the layer with arcpy.

[image]

Oddly enough, I can still access the table from ArcMap, but arcpy is the functionality that I really need.

Given the lack of informative error messages and documentation for arcpy with spatialite, does anyone know what might be causing this? Any suggestions for solutions or workarounds?

Update: Here is a screen showing the layer drawing in ArcMap and returning False in arcpy. This seems like errant behavior. 
[image]

Update 2: I tested again using ArcGIS10.3.1 and it still failed. Apparently you cannot edit sqlite databases in QGIS and retain arcpy functionality.

Comment: You might need to [rebuild the spatial indices](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/modifying-a-spatial-index.htm) or a [repair geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm)?

Comment: @crmackey I tried rebuilding the spatial index in ArcCatalog and got 'Failed to Delete Spatial Index. Invalid spatial column name. The field is not nullable'. I rebuilt it within the Spatialite-GUI and that didn't fix my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by _still access the table from ArcMap_ after using QGIS to modify it. Is ArcMap still open with the data loaded at the same time as your QGIS edit? It sounds odd you can 'see it, access it' in ArcMap, but not access it with arcpy. (Yeah Im inferring that if the QGIS edit did something Arc* doesn't like, it shouldn't work anywhere, not work in some)

Comment: I create the database in Arcpy. Close everything. Open QGIS and add a point. Close everything. Try to access the data in arcpy, get the error above. Close everything. Open ArcMap and drag the layer into the map, it adds and I can view the data and attribute table. Interestingly, using Arcpy.Exists('.\test.sqlite\main.points') returns False. So it really does seems to be an arcpy specific thing.

Comment: I just tried your workflow (everything accept the QGIS part) in ArcMap... and arcpy.Exist works in both 10.3.1 and 10.4. I think SQLLITE was introduced as an option in 10.2, so its possible there was a bug there thats since been fixed? Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks @KHibma. I'll have a go on a machine with 10.3.1 and see if that fixes my issue or if there is something about editing with QGIS that is the matter.